# How center items in Tailwind css

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-3

How to center the content or items on small sizes in Tailwind. I did all the alignment classes that are available in Tailwind but it's not working. It's Tailwind V3

```
<div class="bg-white pb-8">
  <div class="p-4 pb-0 bg-third-bg sm:max-w-7xl mx-auto">
    <div class="sm:flex sm:max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8 sm:items-center sm:justify-between bg-white p-6">
      <div class="sm:flex sm:flex-col sm:items-center sm:justify-center sm:space-y-4 md:w-4/12">
        <div class="sm:flex">
          <img src="https://educlever.beplusthemes.com/university/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/forma4.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="sm:flex text-xl font-bold">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
        <div class="sm:flex sm:text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conse ct amet, conse adipiscing elit dolor sit a amet, conse adipisci</div>
      </div>
      <div class="sm:flex sm:flex-col sm:items-center sm:justify-center sm:space-y-4 md:w-4/12">
        <div class="sm:flex">
          <img src="https://educlever.beplusthemes.com/university/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/forma3.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="sm:flex text-xl font-bold">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
        <div class="sm:flex sm:text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conse ct amet, conse adipiscing elit dolor sit a amet, conse adipisci</div>
      </div>
      <div class="sm:flex sm:flex-col sm:items-center sm:justify-center sm:space-y-4 md:w-4/12">
        <div class="sm:flex">
          <img src="https://educlever.beplusthemes.com/university/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/forma2.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="sm:flex text-xl font-bold">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
        <div class="sm:flex sm:text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conse ct amet, conse adipiscing elit dolor sit a amet, conse adipisci</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/dBKsusYFvi?size=540x720

Comment: "Not working" is not a technical description of a problem.

Answer (score 11):

This is typically done with Tailwind's `flex` or `grid`.

Since it looks like you're working with `flex` already, I've included that example first.

### 1. Flex

If you intend to use Tailwind's `flex`, wrapping your items in a container that has `flex` and `justify-center` is all you need. Keep in mind these classes need to be on the *direct parent element* of the items you want centered.

```
<div class="flex justify-center">
  <div>centered item</div>
</div>
```

The below example would apply the styles to screens at or above whatever size is assigned to `sm` in your Tailwind theme, or `480px` for the default - the equivalent of `@media (min-width: 480px)`.

```
<div class="sm:flex sm:justify-center">
  <div>centered item</div>
</div>
```

Here's a snippet you can run to illustrate:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="flex bg-slate-100 p-8 justify-center">
  <div class='text-2xl'>centered item</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### 2. Grid

With `grid`, you just need a parent with `grid` and `justify-items-center`.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="grid grid-cols-1 justify-items-center bg-slate-100 p-8">
  <div class='text-2xl'>centered item</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd be sure to [check out the docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/justify-content#center) as well, they're quite helpful with plenty of examples.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that I have to use grid justify-items to solve that issue

```
<div class="bg-white pb-8">
    <div class="p-4 pb-0 bg-third-bg sm:max-w-7xl mx-auto">
        <div class="sm:flex sm:max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8 sm:items-center sm:justify-between bg-white p-6">
            <div class="grid justify-items-center text-center">
                <img class="w-32" src="https://educlever.beplusthemes.com/university/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/forma4.png" alt="" />
                <div class="text-xl font-bold">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
                <div class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conse ct amet, conse adipiscing elit dolor sit a amet, conse adipisci</div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid justify-items-center">
                <img class="w-32" src="https://educlever.beplusthemes.com/university/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/forma3.png" alt="" />
                <div class="sm:flex text-xl font-bold">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
                <div class="sm:flex sm:text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conse ct amet, conse adipiscing elit dolor sit a amet, conse adipisci</div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid justify-items-center">
                <img class="w-32" src="https://educlever.beplusthemes.com/university/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/forma2.png" alt="" />
                <div class="sm:flex text-xl font-bold">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
                <div class="sm:flex sm:text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conse ct amet, conse adipiscing elit dolor sit a amet, conse adipisci</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```